# "A good news-reader can become a good newsreader!" Is this correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this sentence correct?

> **A good news reader *(or news-reader?)* can become a good newsreader**

To get my point, look at these sentences -

> If you are a good *cricketer*, the upcoming season is really good for you.

Here, I'm talking to a person who plays cricket well. The upcoming season is good for him in some ways.

> If you are a keen *learner*, this tutorial is really good for you.

Here, I'm talking to a person who is quite good at learning things and thus, the tutorial is helpful to him.

**SO...**

> If you are a good ***news reader***, you can become a good [newsreader](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/newsreader).

Here, I'm talking to a person who *reads* news quite interestingly with perfect intonation and pronunciation. In other words, he's good at reading news.

Note: I'm **not** looking for an alternative sentence. Just want to discuss whether or not the sentence in concern is correct with some clarification of using two same words that make a noun *(newsreader)* as well as an (?)adjective *(news-reader)*.

Comment: To me, a *newsreader* is an NNTP client.  Although I'd understand the other meaning of *newsreader* in context, I'd never use it with that meaning.

Comment: Arguably disturbing but correct in usage. My grandfather reads news really good with his awesome voice but I don't think he can catch the speed of a newsreader..

Comment: @BerkerYüceer I guess it should be *well* in that grandpa's example instead of *good*

Comment: @MaulikV Thank you! I am no expert but pretty sure this sentence of yours is correct. Not in meaning but in grammar.

Comment: Is this American or British English? I'm American, and I thought a "newsreader" was a kind of computer program or mobile app that let you read the news. But apparently the British use "newsreader" to mean a person who reports the news on the TV or radio. It would help us to answer if we knew whether this was American or British English.

Comment: The [American edition of Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/newsreader?showCookiePolicy=true) labels _newsreader_ as `mainly British`. I don't recall hearing the term before. In the U.S., we'd probably use the term _news [anchor](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/anchor)_ to convey the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is grammatically and semantically correct, but by itself doesn't clearly communicate what you want it to mean.

If you're intending to use it in a context where being confusing is good—for example, it's a playful title for an article and you want people to read the article to find out what the confusing title is supposed to mean—then that's fine and it works! If you want it to be clearly understandable on its own though, it won't convey what you want it to.

The reason it's going to be confusing is because the simplest understanding of "a good news reader" is being good at understanding the news you read. The meaning you intend, being good at reading the news aloud, is a correct alternative meaning of the words, but it's rarer. An audience is unlikely to guess that something should be read with a rarer meaning when the more common meaning is also grammatically and semantically correct.